# Javascript function not waiting for AJAX response

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an AJAX function called `flagIt()`, which is called from within another function called `validateForm()`. `validateForm()` is executed on submit.

```
function validateForm(){
    var error = "";
    //do stuff to validate form
    if(error == ""){
        flagIt();
    }else{
      window.alert(error);
      return false;
    }
}
```

As it appears above, it will call `flagIt()`, but then allows the form to submit without waiting for the response from my AJAX which is performed within `flagIt()`.

If I add a `window.alert('something');` after the call to `flagIt()` It has time to execute the AJAX and everything works.

How can I force the function `validateForm()` to wait for my AJAX before allowing the form to submit without adding an alert?

I have tried `return flagIt()`.

**EDIT**

To clarify, I am not submitting the form in AJAX. I'm updating a database.

Comment: you can either use `async:false` in ajax or `return false;` after `flagIt()` and submit your form in ajax's success function

Comment: Where is your ajax function, please show code.

Comment: Do you not understand what the "A" is in "Ajax"?

Comment: if you are just updating the database and don't need to submit the form means, just return `false` after `flagIt()`!

Comment: I am submitting the form, just not thru AJAX.

Comment: OOOOOhhhh i see what you mean.. @ClydeLobo answerd the question in one word.. set async to false and it works like a charm. put it in the answers and I'll choosoe it

Comment: Use `XMLHttpRequest` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just adding to my comment

Your code does not stop at `flagIt()` because its an AJAX , which is *Asynchronous*

If you want it to stop there and wait for the AJAX call to finish you will have to set the `async` flag to `false`

`xmlhttpp.open("GET",url,false);`

And yes, you can call that **SJAX**

Answer (score 3):

you can either use `async:false` in ajax or `return false;` after `flagIt()` and submit your form in ajax's success function using `document.myform.submit();`

Comment: I tried `document.getElementById("form2").submit();` in the `onreadystatechange` function but it's just not submitting the form for some reason. Why might that be?