# Javascript not waiting for ajax with bootstrap-wizard.js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a [bootstrap-wizard](http://www.panopta.com/2013/02/06/bootstrap-application-wizard-2/) as follows:

```
<div class="wizard-card" data-cardname="credential">
            <h3>Credential</h3>
            <div class="wizard-input-section">
                <p>Username</p>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Busername" name="Busername" placeholder="Username" required data-parsley-type="alphanum" data-validate="checkNameAvailable" data-msg="Alphanumeric allowed only" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>Password</p>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Bpassword" name="Bpassword" placeholder="Password" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>Re-type Password</p>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="Bpassowrd2" name="Bpassword2" placeholder="Retype Password"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The input `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Busername" name="Busername" placeholder="Username" required data-parsley-type="alphanum" data-validate="checkNameAvailable" data-msg="Alphanumeric allowed only" />` calls the **checkNameAvailable** function to make validation.

**checkNameAvailable function:**
Which makes an ajax call to check if the name is available or not.

```
function checkNameAvailable(el){
        if($("#"+$(el).attr('id')).parsley().isValid()){
            var data =  $(el).val();
            if($(el).attr('id') == "Busername"){
                var type = "B";
            }else{
                var type = "I";
            }
            $.ajax({
                  method: "POST",
                  url: "isUserAvailableCommon",
                  async: false,
                  data: {Busername: data, _token: $("#_token").val(), _type: type },
                    success: function(msg) {
                        var retValue = {};
                        if(msg == "OK"){
                            retValue.status = true;
                            console.log(retValue);
                            return retValue;
                        }else{
                            retValue.status = false;
                            console.log(retValue);
                            return retValue;
                        }
                    }

             });
    }
}
```

The problem is that the variable `retValue` is not returned to the bootstrap-wizard validation.

However if i try like this it works but not when implementing with ajax

```
function checkNameAvailable(el){
  var retValue = {};
  retValue.status = false;
  return retValue;
}
```

Any idea how to make it work with ajax? I have tried callbacks and methods described in [Javascript function not waiting for AJAX response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977234/javascript-function-not-waiting-for-ajax-response)but it is still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to change your function like this:

```
function checkNameAvailable(el){
        var dfd = $.Deferred();

        if($("#"+$(el).attr('id')).parsley().isValid()){
            var data =  $(el).val();
            if($(el).attr('id') == "Busername"){
                var type = "B";
            }else{
                var type = "I";
            }

            $.ajax({
                  method: "POST",
                  url: "isUserAvailableCommon",
                  data: {Busername: data, _token: $("#_token").val(), _type: type },
                    success: function(msg) {
                        var retValue = {};
                        if(msg == "OK"){
                            retValue.status = true;
                            console.log(retValue);
                            dfd.resolve(retValue);
                        }else{
                            retValue.status = false;
                            console.log(retValue);
                            dfd.resolve(retValue);
                        }
                    }

             });
    }

    return dfd.promise();
}

// after this you can use 
// checkNameAvailable in this 
// way. 

checkNameAvailable(el).done(function(retValue) {
    console.log(retValue);
});
```

Read my comment and example of function usage. When we using promise 
the code can be asynchronous. You must not async: false - this is not 
very good idea at all.

Edit: 
Synchronous ajax request is not very good idea but existing code 
base expect synchronous function so your function must be 
changed in this way:

```
function checkNameAvailable(el) {
    var result;

    if ($("#" + $(el).attr('id')).parsley().isValid()) {
        var data = $(el).val();
        if ($(el).attr('id') == "Busername") {
            var type = "B";
        } else {
            var type = "I";
        }
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "isUserAvailableCommon",
            async: false,
            data: {
                Busername: data,
                _token: $("#_token").val(),
                _type: type
            },
            success: function(msg) {
                var retValue = {};
                if (msg == "OK") {
                    retValue.status = true;
                    console.log(retValue);
                    result = retValue;
                } else {
                    retValue.status = false;
                    console.log(retValue);
                    result = retValue;
                }
            }

        });
    }

    return result;
}
```

Good luck.

Edit 2:

I have forked the repository of project and add example how to use 
asynchronous into validator function. This solution is kind of dirty 
hack but is much better than using synchronous logic.

https://github.com/gonaumov/bootstrap-application-wizard/blob/master/demo/demoAsynchronousValidator.html

I also do a pull request with this changes.

Comment: I have tried it the way you described but have still the same behavior like my codes I tried. It do return me ` Object { status=false}` in the console put the bootstrap-wizard validator is not getting the Object.

Comment: Hmm. Can you post the code that call checkNameAvailable function? I mean the code that expect the object,

Comment: The code that expect the object is the javascript file bootstrap-wizard.js which you can find on http://www.panopta.com/2013/02/06/bootstrap-application-wizard-2/

Comment: I have edited the answer. You can use my last example.